# can superconductors and other meisner materials be used as magnetic shielding in space to protect diamagnetic artificial gravity of 45 teslas?

Tags: gravity, radiation, superconductivity

I have seen people referring to Geim's floating frog that a human in 45 Tesla's would be held to the ground from diamagnetism above them.  A very real but crude artificial gravity using powerful superconductive magnets. The problem was the shrapnel from ferrous outside material would be so attracted it would damage the the ship or the mission. Because the magnet would be so strong the velocity of these projectiles would be overpowerful.  Could superconductors or diamagnetic material like H2O, Bismuth, or even accelerated graphite, shield the huge superconductive magnet in this experiment?

Answer (score 1):

The force exerted by the magnetic field on diamagnetics is not given by its actual value, but *the gradient of its magnitude*. So in truly homogeneous 45T field, no net force would be generated; on the contrary, you could use a strongly varying field to achieve levitation also with weaker field.

The health risks from strong static magnetic fields are uncertain. While people are routinely exposed to fields up to 10 T, there are numerous perceivable effects of it. See, e.g., http://www.who.int/peh-emf/publications/facts/fs299/en/

You are perfectly right that another trouble with "artificial gravity" through magnetic fields is in substantially different interaction with di-/para-/ferro-magnetics.

The fundamental trouble with this is however technical - currently we can not make (nor shield) 45T field with superconductors (AFAIK), and the magnets are large-scale facilities requiring a lot of power and also a very rigid mechanical construction.

Finally, I can not answer the question about using superconducting magnetts to shield any cosmic radiation, but it seems rather like a sci-fi topic to me.